# Custom UI Integration in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

How to integrate custom UI in a iOS application ? Could someone recommend some books or links which describe some general step what i should be aware . Thx

Comment: What do you mean by "custom UI"? Do you want to know how to use the nib and graphical elements, or are you searching for a way to subclass the existing ones, or develop your own from scratch?

Comment: @develoops Kindly Explain your Question Completely .what you want to do ..?

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing that sometimes. Creating custom UI components, I've never used book, just reading some tutorial and Apple's documentation. If you want to create some kind of complex components you'd better learn CoreGraphics and CoreAnimation. That should help you doing great stuff.

You can start with this tutorial : [How To Make a Custom UIView in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view)

I need to warn you on something regarding this kind of projects. Before Xcode 4 you were able to create Interface Builder plugin for your custom UI Components. But they remove this possibility with the latest version. So using your custom UI Components with interface builder is not really nice now, you need to configure your views only within the code, you won't be to change any parameters in Interface builder. You'll only be able to see how it's look like in IB.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot more customisation possibilities now in ios5, so other than creating custom controls you should be able to create most of a custom interface using uikit controls with [appearance](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5) see ADC videos e.g. [WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) Session 114 Customizing the appearance of UIKit controls

For custom controls, look at the ADC videos, e.g. [WWDC 2010](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) Session 141 Crafting Custom Cocoa Views, [WWDC 2010](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) Session 123 Building Animation Driven Interfaces,